# Find and replace multiple values over thousand of records

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sheets, I am trying to write a script that searches and replaces various  semester codes that identify a term and semester and replaces it with readable terms (i.e. 201305 to Summer Semester 2013) over multiple years.

With over 25000 records, I only need specific columns and rows searched as those columns will only contain that data and the previous rows will have already been changed previously.

I have tried various coding options that I have found here but most time out. The script below works when it is a few values to search and repalce. With more than 25, it keeps timing out now.

Now I think that if I just check the specific columns that have values that need to be changed, that could speed it up also. But I keep getting errors when I try to call it and I am not sure how to call those specific columns and rows. I just really need columns R:U checked and rows greater than 14374.

Any suggestions how I can adjust the code below to make it work without causing the page to crash or time out?

Disclaimer - I am not the creator of this code, I found it here and updated it to reflect what I was trying to do as someone's solution to a very similar problem.

This is the code I tried:

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Enrolled");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace Semester Code
replaceInSheet(values, 201301, 'Spring Semester 2013');
replaceInSheet(values, 201305, 'Summer Semester 2013');
replaceInSheet(values, 201308, 'Fall Semester 2013');
replaceInSheet(values, 201401, 'Spring Semester 2014');
replaceInSheet(values, 201405, 'Summer Semester 2014');
replaceInSheet(values, 201408, 'Fall Semester 2014');
replaceInSheet(values, 201501, 'Spring Semester 2015');
replaceInSheet(values, 201505, 'Summer Semester 2015');
replaceInSheet(values, 201508, 'Fall Semester 2015');
replaceInSheet(values, 201601, 'Spring Semester 2016');
replaceInSheet(values, 201605, 'Summer Semester 2016');
replaceInSheet(values, 201608, 'Fall Semester 2016');
replaceInSheet(values, 201701, 'Spring Semester 2017');
replaceInSheet(values, 201705, 'Summer Semester 2017');
replaceInSheet(values, 201708, 'Fall Semester 2017');
replaceInSheet(values, 201801, 'Spring Semester 2018');
replaceInSheet(values, 201805, 'Summer Semester 2018');
replaceInSheet(values, 201808, 'Fall Semester 2018');
replaceInSheet(values, 201901, 'Spring Semester 2019');
replaceInSheet(values, 201905, 'Summer Semester 2019');
replaceInSheet(values, 201908, 'Fall Semester 2019');
replaceInSheet(values, 202001, 'Spring Semester 2020');
replaceInSheet(values, 202005, 'Summer Semester 2020');
replaceInSheet(values, 202008, 'Fall Semester 2020');
replaceInSheet(values, 202101, 'Spring Semester 2021');
replaceInSheet(values, 202105, 'Summer Semester 2021');
replaceInSheet(values, 202108, 'Fall Semester 2021');
replaceInSheet(values, 202201, 'Spring Semester 2022');
replaceInSheet(values, 202205, 'Summer Semester 2022');
replaceInSheet(values, 202208, 'Fall Semester 2022');
replaceInSheet(values, 202301, 'Spring Semester 2023');
replaceInSheet(values, 202305, 'Summer Semester 2023');
replaceInSheet(values, 202308, 'Fall Semester 2023');
replaceInSheet(values, 202401, 'Spring Semester 2024');
replaceInSheet(values, 202405, 'Summer Semester 2024');
replaceInSheet(values, 202408, 'Fall Semester 2024');
replaceInSheet(values, 202501, 'Spring Semester 2025');
replaceInSheet(values, 202505, 'Summer Semester 2025');
replaceInSheet(values, 202508, 'Fall Semester 2025');
  

 // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

It results in timing out since I suspect there are so many values to search and replace over so many columns. It is currently searching A1:CB22548

Answer (score 0):

Of course I can't test this but I believe it will work for your situation.

Right now you are looping through the entire array for each value you want to replace.  Then looping again through the entire array for the next value.

I create an array of values to search for and then use `Array.findIndex()` to see if the cell contains a match.  Then I replace the value in the `values` array with the new string.  This way I only loop through the big array once.

**Code.gs**

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Enrolled");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  let oldValues = [ 201301, 201305, 201308, 201401, 201405, 201408, 201501, 201505,
                    201508, 201601, 201605, 201608, 201701, 201705, 201708, 201801,
                    201805, 201808, 201901, 201905, 201908, 202001, 202005, 202008,
                    202101, 202105, 202108, 202201, 202205, 202208, 202301, 202305,
                    202308, 202401, 202405, 202408, 202501, 202505, 202508 ];

  let newValues = [ "Spring Semester 2013", "Summer Semester 2013", "Fall Semester 2013",
                    "Spring Semester 2014", "Summer Semester 2014", "Fall Semester 2014",
                    "Spring Semester 2015", "Summer Semester 2015", "Fall Semester 2015",
                    "Spring Semester 2016", "Summer Semester 2016", "Fall Semester 2016",
                    "Spring Semester 2017", "Summer Semester 2017", "Fall Semester 2017",
                    "Spring Semester 2018", "Summer Semester 2018", "Fall Semester 2018",
                    "Spring Semester 2019", "Summer Semester 2019", "Fall Semester 2019",
                    "Spring Semester 2020", "Summer Semester 2020", "Fall Semester 2020",
                    "Spring Semester 2021", "Summer Semester 2021", "Fall Semester 2021",
                    "Spring Semester 2022", "Summer Semester 2022", "Fall Semester 2022",
                    "Spring Semester 2023", "Summer Semester 2023", "Fall Semester 2023",
                    "Spring Semester 2024", "Summer Semester 2024", "Fall Semester 2024",
                    "Spring Semester 2025", "Summer Semester 2025", "Fall Semester 2025" ];   

  values.forEach( row => {
      row.forEach( (column,index) => {
          let match = oldValues.findIndex(column);
          if( match >= 0 ) row[index] = newValues[match];
        }
      );
    }
  );  

 // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}
```

**References**

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)